# set Java Bean Timeout

Tags: jpa, javabeans, glassfish-3, jta

Because the client (php) has a timeout of 5 seconds when running a query via REST on my glassfish app, I would like to setup the glassfish java beans methods so that they also "give up" after 5 seconds. Otherwise the method get's on going and things saved twice on the sql database.

```
PHP                         Glassfish             DB

Query -- save -->           saveSomething   -->   insert....  
TIMEOUT 5 sek 
Query --> save again -->    saveSomething   -->   another insert...
```

Isn't there a @Timeout annotation that stops the method after 4900 ms?

I could only find s.t. inside the sun(glassfish)-ejb-jar.xml  4

Is that the right way, and if what is the minimum config there. I don't know the sun-ejb-jar.xml.

I don't want to setup a global timeout for everything. That would make problems for long running tasks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution with some manual work. You remember the time when the method starts and compare before the method ends. If the time spend is greater than x you throw a ForceTimeoutException (RuntimeException) and so everything is rolled back.

```
public void doSomethingOnDatabase() {
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    ..... other programm code ....
   if (sw.elapsed()>TIMEOUT_VALUE) {
       throw new ForceTimeoutException(sw.elapsed());
   }
}
```

A more elegant solution wanted!

something like 
    @MethodTimeoutForceRollback(5000) 
on top of the method.